# How to set Padding Type for CoreML Delegate on Tensorflow Lite to fix `PoolingLayerBuilder (MEAN)_1' is not set.`?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, coreml, google-cloud-automl

I recently trained an object detection model on Google's Vision platform and exported it to a TensorFlow Lite edge model.

I receive this error in Xcode when running on an iOS device with a CoreML delegate:

> validator error: Padding type for the pooling layer 'PoolingLayerBuilder (MEAN)_1' is not set.

When running on iOS using TensorFlow lite with a CoreML delegate I get this error:

> Error compiling model Error reading protobuf spec. validator error: Padding type for the pooling layer 'PoolingLayerBuilder (MEAN)_1' is not set.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Updating my pods to make sure I'm on the TensorFlowLiteSwift nightly build
- Running on CPU only (the model works, so I know its a CoreML delegate problem)
- Making sure CoreMLDelegate is using the latest version of CoreML (3)

**Next Steps?**

- Try to modify the TFLite file itself to set the padding type for the pooling layer somehow. It's not obvious how to do this
- Try to modify the CoreML delegate to set the padding type to a default? Somewhere in this file? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/nightly/tensorflow/lite/delegates/coreml/builders/pooling_layer_builder.cc#L54

Is that the right approach or is there an easier solution I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

In order to edit a TFlite model, I recommend you to use this python library called [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron). I did not tested this with an object detection model yet [I will update this comment along the day], however, I managed to have access to the model itself and to modify its configuration.

When you install Netron, and call the model.tflite as `netron 'model.tflite'`,a server link will show up in your command shell. When you click it, you will have access to the graphic mode of your model. When you click a layer, a set of properties will show up, which you can modify there. I managed to notice this thanks to this [github comments](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48879). I think this will let you solve your issue.

Meanwhile, I will try to modify the CoreML version of my model as soon as I've a new deployed model of an object detection case. I will keep you updated!

Let me know if this has helped you so far.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you could try:

1. Convert the model to .onnx format using [tensorflow-onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx).
2. Instead of converting .tflite to CoreML model, you can try convert tensorflow model(.h5, SavedModel, tf.keras.Model, concrete function) directly to CoreML. Ref: [Tensorflow 2 Conversion](https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/tensorflow-2)